# use regex to check that start of user input has exactly two curly brackets

Tags: regex, ruby

I'm trying to make sure that user input is exactly `{{user_input}}` in regards to the brackets. text can be anything as long as it's a number or character. `{{(.*?)}}` works to make sure that the two brackets exist at the beginning and end of the input but I  also want to make sure there are only two brackets. I've tried `[^{]{{(.*?)}}[^}]` and `{{2}(.*?)}{2}`, but it still counts `{{{user_input}}` as valid.

Comment: Have a look: https://regex101.com/r/rBIz3H/1

Comment: Is `"{{a{b}}c}}"` valid? Is `"{{}}"` valid? You say `"text can be anything as long as it's a number or character"`.  Numbers (digits) are characters and text is by definition a string of characters, so that statement is meaningless. You need to state which characters may appear in which locations in the string.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I'll keep that in mind! I think folks that helped me out knew what I meant and were able to come up with something that worked better than my approach

Comment: Please answer my two questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
/^{{([^{}]*?)}}$/
```

to exclude curly braces in the middle of user input.

Answer (score 1):

`(?<![{])a` => There must not "{" character before the "a"

`a(?![}])` => There must not "}" character after the "a"

`a([^{}]*)a` => All characters except "{" and "}" between "a"s

Solution:

```
(?<![{]){{([^{}]*?)}}(?![}])
```

Sample: https://regex101.com/r/OiLk8S/1

Comment: this works exactly as I needed it to, thank you!